# Get next billing date from Laravel Cashier

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-cashier

I have subscribed a user to a subscription plan through Laravel's Cashier package. I now want to display the date the user will next be billed, however this doesn't appear to be an available through the Billable trait.

How do I get the next billing date?
Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution is to use the `asStripeCustomer` method:

```
// Retrieve the timestamp from Stripe
$timestamp = $user->asStripeCustomer()["subscriptions"]->data[0]["current_period_end"];

// Cast to Carbon instance and return
return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp($timestamp)->toFormattedDateString();
```

Note that I've only tested this with a user who has a single subscription - `data[0]`.

You may need to alter this code for multiple subscriptions or if the user has cancelled and started another subscription.

Comment: This solution worked for me. @John1984, it's OK to accept your own answer.

Comment: may I ask you to take a look at a l Stripe rekated question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238551/stripe-cannot-create-a-plan ?

Answer (score 14):

Building on previous answers, here's what's working for me:

```
private function getSubscriptionRenewDate($plan)
{
    $sub = Auth::user()->subscription($plan)->asStripeSubscription();
    return Carbon::createFromTimeStamp($sub->current_period_end)->format('F jS, Y');
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Subscriptions also have a `->asStripeSubscription()` method that gives you access to the values just for that subscription. So you could do:

```
// Retrieve the timestamp from Stripe
$timestamp = $subscription->current_period_end;

// Cast to Carbon instance and return
return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp($timestamp)->toFormattedDateString();
```