# Stripe - cannot create a plan

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using [Laravel Cashier](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/billing) to implement a recurring payment system. I need a plan to make subscription. Stripe  [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans/create)  says : "You can create plans using the API, or in the Stripe Dashboard." But when I go to dashboard by clicking on the link there , I do not see any way to create any plan.

**Question :** So how do I create a plan there so that I can use it in the server side Laravel Cashier Stripe  implementation in the following way ?

```
$user->newSubscription('main', $plan)->create($token, ['email' =>$email,]);
```

I need the plan to be used as the value of `$plan`  variable .

Answer (score 1):

The dashboard was recently updated to use the newer Price abstraction. You can use the new recurring Price objects in place of plans. Set the value of $plan to the ID of a Price [created in the dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/products). Prices have IDs like `price_xxx`. Note that this will only work if the price is a recurring price.

Comment: Suppose I have want to make a subscription package of $30 per month basis. In stripe , if 50 users want to subscribe to the package then does it mean that 50 subscriptions with 50 different plan ids or price ids have to be created for them ?

Comment: You would have 1 Product in Stripe and 1 Price in Stripe and 50 Subscriptions each with items pointing to that price. You only need multiple Prices if you are charging in different currencies or for different durations (like $30/month is one price and $300/year is another price for the same product).

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide you a blade page example. Since I copied this from a draft I used some time ago, please adapt your own blade template with the forms and relevant content:

**create_plan.blade.php**

```
@extends('inc.base')
@section('title', 'Create Plan')
@section('content')
{{-- ----------------------------- --}}
<div class="app-main__inner">
    <div class="app-page-title">
        <div class="page-title-wrapper">
            <div class="page-title-heading">
                <div class="page-title-icon"><i class="pe-7s-plane icon-gradient bg-tempting-azure"></i></div>
                <div>Subscription | Create Plan<div class="page-title-subheading">Testing subscription plan creation.</div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="main-card mb-3 card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="{{ route('create_plan_route_name_post') }}" method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Plan Prefix</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="prefix" type="number" placeholder="Plan Prefix">
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Plan Name</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Plan Name">
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Amount</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="amount" type="text" placeholder="Amount">
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Trial Days</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="trial_days" type="number" placeholder="Trial Days">
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Currency</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="currency" type="text" placeholder="Currency">
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Interval Count</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="interval_count" type="number" placeholder="Interval Count">
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Billing Period</label>
                                <select name="billing_period" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="" disabled></option>
                                    <option value="week">Weekly</option>
                                    <option value="month">Monthly</option>
                                    <option value="year">Yearly</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <div class="form-group text-center">
                                <button type="submit" id="card-button" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{-- ----------------------------- --}}
@endsection
```

in your web.php, create a route `create_plan_route_name_post`. Feel free to name it as you like. Example:

obs. I'm assuming that you have a controller `SubscriptionController`. If you don't, add this at the top of your **web.php**:

> use App\Http\Controllers\SubscriptionController;

**web.php**

```
//this is how you access the blade page
  Route::get('/create-plan', function(){
        return view('path.create_plan');
    })->name('create_plan_route_name_get');


//this is the route for the form submission
  Route::post('/create-plan', [SubscriptionController::class, 'savePlan'])->name('create_plan_route_name_post');
```

Again, if you don't have the controller `SubscriptionController`, create it running `php artisan make:controller SubscriptionController`. Now, inside the controller, add this function:

**SubscriptionController**

```
public function savePlan(Request $request)
{
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('YOUR STRIPE API KEY'));
    try {
        $plan = Plan::create([
            'amount' => ($request->amount * 100),
            'currency' => $request->currency,
            'interval' => $request->billing_period,
            'interval_count' => $request->interval_count,
            'trial_period_days' => $request->trial_days,
            'product' => [
                'name' => $request->name
            ]
        ]);
        ModelsPlan::create([
            'plan_id' => $plan->id,
            'prefix' => $request->prefix,
            'name' => $request->name,
            'price' => $plan->amount,
            'billing_method' => $plan->interval,
            'currency' => $plan->currency,
            'interval_count' => $plan->interval_count,
            'trial_days' => $request->trial_days
        ]);
        return "success";
    }
    catch(Exception $ex) {
        dd($ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Also, make sure this is present on top of the `SubscriptionController`:

> use App\Models\Plan as ModelsPlan;

Now let's make a Model for the plans. Run `php artisan make:model Plan` and navigate to App\Models\Plan.php and replace everything with this:

**Plan.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Plan extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'plan_id',
        'prefix',
        'name',
        'billing_method',
        'interval_count',
        'trial_days',
        'price',
        'currency',
    ];
}
```

This should be enough to get you creating plans and start building and testing your payment wall platform.